# Is it possible to inflate a CustomLayout : FrameLayout in Xamarin in its own constructors and own class methods?

Tags: android, xamarin, custom-controls, layout-inflater, android-framelayout

Here is the example I would like to inflate... it is just a FrameLayout and I have the Layout axml file... I could inflate the layout from the parent of this FrameLayout (a Fragment)... I want this Custom FrameLayout in other fragments. In the method initialize() the compiler says  Error CS1604: Cannot assign to '' because it is read-only (CS1604) (MyProject.Mono) and then  Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Android.Widget.FrameLayout' to 'MyProject.Mono.ViewArtistAlbumTrack'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266) (Navi.Mono)

```
     /// <summary>
     /// View artist album track.
     /// This framelayout is especific for ...
     /// </summary>
       public class ViewArtistAlbumTrack : FrameLayout

{
    /// <summary>
    /// The adapter.
    /// </summary>
    public ExpandableAATitemAdapter adapter = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// a plain ExpandableListView
    /// </summary>
    public ExpandableListView expandable = null; 
    /// <summary>
    /// View that triggers something sliding up
    /// </summary>
    public Button albumdown = null; 
    public Button trackdown = null; 

    /// <summary>
    /// The list just AAT items. AAT is for Artist Album Track 
    /// </summary>
    public List<AATitem> list = null; 


    public ViewArtistAlbumTrack (Context context) :
    base (context)
    {
        this.trackdown = new Button(this.Context); 
        this.albumdown = new Button(this.Context);
        this.expandable = new ExpandableListView(this.Context); 
        Initialize ();


    }

    public ViewArtistAlbumTrack (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
    base (context, attrs)
    {
        this.trackdown = new Button(this.Context); 
        this.albumdown = new Button(this.Context);
        this.expandable = new ExpandableListView(this.Context); 

        Initialize ();
    }

    public ViewArtistAlbumTrack (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
    base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {

        Initialize ();
    }


    public void Initialize ()
    {
        try
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater =     (LayoutInflater)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            this = (FrameLayout)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ViewAAT, null);


            Console.WriteLine("done succesfully: "+ System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString() ); 
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("exception at "
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString() + " : "
                + exception.Source.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine ("exception at "
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString()+ " : "
                + exception.Message.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine ("exception at "
                +  System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString()+ " : "
                + exception.StackTrace.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine ("exception at " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString()+ " : "
                + exception.TargetSite.ToString() );
        }// end of catch()

        //this.expandable.SetAdapter(new ExpandableAATitemAdapter(Application.Context, this.list));
    }

    protected override void  OnFinishInflate() 
    {
        try
        {

            this.trackdown = new Button(this.Context); 

            this.albumdown = new Button(this.Context);

            this.expandable = new ExpandableListView(this.Context); 

            this.expandable = FindViewById<ExpandableListView> (Resource.Id.aatexpandableid); 
            this.trackdown  = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.aattracksbid);
            this.albumdown  = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.aatabumsbid);

            this.trackdown.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone; 
            this.albumdown.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone; 
            Console.WriteLine("done succesfully: "+ System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString() ); 

        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("exception at "
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString() + " : "
                + exception.Source.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine ("exception at "
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString()+ " : "
                + exception.Message.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine ("exception at "
                +  System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString()+ " : "
                + exception.StackTrace.ToString() );
            Console.WriteLine ("exception at " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()+ "  " 
                + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString()+ " : "
                + exception.TargetSite.ToString() );
        }// end of catch()

    }
```

}

Comment: Are you defining it in your xml as a `FrameLayout` or as your custom type?

Comment: in my axml as a custom type (ViewArtistAlbumTrack) and then as a FrameLayout trying to cast as a ViewArtistAlbumTrack later.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue may be with this line:

```
 this = (FrameLayout)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ViewAAT, null);
```

That isn't the right way to load a layout in to your view. If your view is a custom `FrameLayout` with some child views then you could inflate your xml into a `FrameLayout` and take references to the views within it e.g.

```
var frame = (FrameLayout)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ViewAAT, null);
this.trackdown = frame.FindViewById<Button>(...);
// find your other views here
```

Comment: solved that's the right answer... but it forces to created more layouts and views... it is another option.

Comment: The views would be created anyway, this is just the best way to get hold of them. You could also use `this` as the container when you inflate the views if you don't want an extra `FrameLayout` instance.